What happens if sudo rm -rf /* is done in WSL?
NOTE: DO NOT USE THIS COMMAND UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING
From what I've find on the internet, the sudo rm -rf /* command wipes out everything in the linux system. If this command is run on WSL, what would happen?
Would it wipe out only the linux system or will it wipe out everything on the drive it is located in?
Would it be able to wipe out any drive that can be reached within WSL?
Would it wipe out everything except files that require Admin access?
I want to get into WSL linux but I want to know what precautions I should take when it comes to running certain commands in WSL and how they make affect files within the windows system.

https://superuser.com/q/1746337/334516 https://superuser.com/q/1765900/334516 https://superuser.com/q/1190510/334516

They were very insightful, Thank you!

It's easy to find out; go boot up a disposable copy of Windows with WSL and see for yourself :)

Unfortunately I don't have a disposable copy of windows

It's been a while since I did so, but is it that hard to boot up a trial version these days? Or an Insider preview version or something like that?

@muru any windows installation these days can be used without activation for a few days, and you can download the installaton media directly from microsoft.

I believe a bootable version of windows can be created with windows ISO, aflash drive and RUFUS, which would make an ideal testing environment. Unfortuntely, I could not find a good enough flash drive that will be able to boot windows where I live.

You could always experiment w/ VirtualBox.

Suffice to say that, since the host filesystem is mounted read-write at e. g. /mnt/c, Very Bad Things will happen.

If the host filesystem is unmounted, would it prevent files from the host machine from being deleted?

It's possible that crucial parts of the WSL subsystem itself may be deleted and require a reinstallation of the Windows component or indeed possibly the underlying OS.  The only reasonably safe way to test this is on a VM with its network interface disabled and doubly-checking there is no hypervisor-driven filesystem syncing going on.
